# Why password change failed? chpasswd: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, docker

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y openssh-server sudo 
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1000 remote_user
USER remote_user
WORKDIR /home/remote_user
RUN mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh
COPY remotecentos.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN stat /etc/passwd
RUN  echo 'remote_user:*****2599*****' | chpasswd -c SHA256
RUN service ssh start
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

I got error

```
Step 9/13 : RUN stat /etc/passwd
 ---> Running in 7147677000bd
  File: /etc/passwd
  Size: 1325        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 37h/55d Inode: 22961332    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-10-06 12:45:10.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2022-10-06 12:45:10.000000000 +0000
Change: 2022-10-06 12:45:11.197943157 +0000
 Birth: 2022-10-06 12:45:11.197943157 +0000
Removing intermediate container 7147677000bd
 ---> 7b37835f7f2c
Step 10/13 : RUN  echo 'remote_user:******' | chpasswd -c SHA256
 ---> Running in faae63d7fd92
chpasswd: Permission denied.
chpasswd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

How to fix permissions inside container?

How should I change the passwd line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile changes the current user to `remote_user` before invoking `chpasswd`.  To use `chpasswd`, you need to be root.  You might want to move that `RUN` line (and any other command that requires super-user privileges) before the `USER` line.  I'm also expecting that the starting of the `ssh` service will fail for similar reasons.